# Stop HighCharts change transparency of another series on hover of one series

Tags: highcharts

By default , when i hover on one series , other series get some transparent.

How can i disable this behavior?

this `hover: { enabled: false}` not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the `opacity` property for inactive state:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            inactive: {
                opacity: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7fmcp0da/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.inactive.opacity

Comment: This only works for the type: 'column', does anyone know how to use it in line??

Comment: Hi @José Araújo, That solution also works with `line` series. Please compare these two jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xg648rzf/, http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/scavjt7o/